# How does ELK Curator manage monthly/weekly indexes when the "time-unit" = "days"

Tags: elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-curator

We have a custom wrapper on top of the standard elasticsearch and curator implementation at our company. I would like to know what would be the behavior of curator dealing with "Monthly/Weekly" indexes when the default "time-unit" is set to "days".

**I cannot override the default "time-unit"

Here is example format of how our monthly/weekly indexes are named

**Format of Monthly Indexes**

```
logstash-test-monthly-2018.01
logstash-test-monthly-2018.02
logstash-test-monthly-2018.03
logstash-test-monthly-2018.04
...
...
logstash-test-monthly-2018.12
```

**Format of Weekly Indexes**

```
logstash-test-weekly-2018.01
logstash-test-weekly-2018.02
...
...
...
logstash-test-weekly-2018.51
logstash-test-weekly-2018.52
```

**Delete_Index.yml - Curator delete instructions**

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: true
    filters:
      - exclude: true
        filtertype: kibana
      - exclude: false
        kind: regex
        filtertype: pattern
        value: .*-monthly-.*
      - range_to: 0
        filtertype: period
        source: name
        range_from: -60
        period_type: relative
        timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
        exclude: true
        unit: days
    description: Delete indices more than X days old
  2:
    action: delete_indices
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: true
    filters:
      - exclude: true
        filtertype: kibana
      - exclude: false
        kind: regex
        filtertype: pattern
        value: .*-weekly-.*
      - range_to: 0
        filtertype: period
        source: name
        range_from: -30
        period_type: relative
        timestring: '%Y.%m.%d'
        exclude: true
        unit: days
```

Implementing the above config with the monthly index retention being 60 days and weekly index retention was 30 days.

**The config was executed on **April,4th,2018** and the result was**

Monthly Indexes retained after execution

```
logstash-test-monthly-2018.03
logstash-test-monthly-2018.04
```

Since the above indexes ^^ only contain 31+4=35 days of index data and not 60 days worth as expected.

**I was expecting curator will retain the following indexes**

```
logstash-test-monthly-2018.02
logstash-test-monthly-2018.03
logstash-test-monthly-2018.04
```

Can anyone explain why curator is unable to retain 60days worth of indexes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TL;DR**: February has a shorter number of days in it, and the `age` calculation is a multiple of seconds * the appropriate number of `unit`s.

All of this is explained in the [`age` filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/filtertype_age.html#_age_calculation) on Elastic's site.

> **age filter vs. period filter**
>
> The time differential means of calculation can lead to frustration.
>
> Setting unit to `months`, and `unit_count` to `3` will actually calculate
>   the age as `3*30*24*60*60`, which is `7776000` seconds. This may be a big
>   deal. If the date is 2017-01-01T02:30:00Z, or `1483237800` in epoch
>   time, subtracting `7776000` seconds makes `1475461800`, which is
>   2016-10-03T02:30:00Z. If you were to try to match `monthly` indices,
>   `index-2016.12`, `index-2016.11`, `2016.10`, `2016.09`, etc., then both
>   `index-2016.09` and `index-2016.10` will be `older` than the cutoff date.
>   This may result in unintended behavior.
>
> Another way this can cause issues is with `weeks`. Weekly indices may
>   start on Sunday or Monday. The `age` filter’s calculation doesn’t take
>   this into consideration, and merely tests the difference between
>   execution time and the timestamp on the index (from any source).
>
> Another means of selecting indices and snapshots is the [`period`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/filtertype_period.html) filter,
>   which is perhaps a better choice for selecting weeks and months as it
>   compensates for these differences.

Once you understand that the `age` calculation isn't more than multiplying `unit_count` * `unit`'s appropriate amount of seconds, then it makes sense why retention is happening the way it is.  As mentioned, you may do better with the [`period`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.5/filtertype_period.html) filter, as it works with complete days, weeks, months, and years.

Answer (score 0):

```
actions:
  1:
    action: delete_indices
    description: >-
      Delete indices older than 2 months (based on index name), for custom-
      prefixed indices. Ignore the error if the filter does not result in an
      actionable list of indices (ignore_empty_list) and exit cleanly.
    options:
      ignore_empty_list: True
      continue_if_exception: False
      disable_action: False
    filters:
      - filtertype: pattern
        kind: regex
        value: ^(index-pattern).*$
      - filtertype: age
        source: name
        direction: older
        timestring: "%Y.%m"
        unit: months
        unit_count: 2
```

This is the yml config that works for deleting the monthly indices only.